# Laravel group by foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have three models

1. `Project`
2. `Category`
3. `Drawing`

The relationship between them is as follows

1. Drawing `belongs to` a category
2. Drawing also `belongs to` a project

Drawing table:

- id
- name
- project_id
- category_id

Project Table :

- id
- name

Category Table :

- id
- name

I want to print all the drawings of a particular project grouped by category name like so :

CATEGORY X
    * Drawing 1
    * Drawing 2

CATEGORY Y
    * Drawing 3
    * Drawing 4

I do not want to print a category if there is no drawing for this particular project in it.

this is what im stuck at :

```
Project->drawings()->groupBy('category_id');
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: So, What's the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the output you want, it'd be easier to come at the problem from the direction of categories.

The following will find all categories, with drawings belonging to the specified `$projectId`, but only those categories that actually have one or more drawings.

```
$projectId = 123;

$projectScope = function ($query) use ($projectId) {
    return $query->where('project_id', $projectId)
});

$categories = Category::with(['drawings' => $projectScope])
    ->whereHas('drawings', $projectScope)
    ->get();
```

Comment: The drawing table has both, project_id and category_id. Is this the correct way or is there a better way?

Comment: Given the desired output where you're iterating over categories and then drawings, I'd say so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
$categories = Category::whereIn('id',$project->drawings()
                      ->groupBy('category_id')
                      ->pluck('category_id')
              )->get();
```

Now, Iterate over `$categories` like

```
@foreach($categories as $category)

    // display category name as {{$category->name}}

    @foreach($category->drawings() as $drawing)

         // display drawings as {{$drawing->name}}

    @endforeach

@endfoeach
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: But this will loop through all the drawings that belongs to a category. I want to print only the drawings that belongs to the given project.